# Existence and name of "Step Number" scheme for extended derivation of step functions?

Tags: integration, derivatives, step-function

Surely the following concept must have been thought of:

The extended-derivative of the step function f(x)={x<0 : 0 ; x>=0 : 1 } shall be defined as g(x)={x≠0:0; x==0:(0,1)}

Where (0,1) is a "Step Number" keeping track of the step.

Integral of g at 0 in interval ±ε is 1 for all ε>0.

(Higher order derivatives would lead to higher order "Step Numbers" (0,0,1) etc.)

Surely this must have been invented before and thus have a name? Or would such a system lead to irreconcilable contradictions?

Comment: Dirac Delta function?

Comment: Dirac Delta functions are very close to the answer, thanks. Reading about it exposed "hyperreal numbers" which are even closer to the answer. Hyperreal Calculus or Nonstandard calculus might be what I was looking for … investigating …

Comment: Actually Dirac Delta is not a function but a distribution. Hence distributions are probably what you are looking for. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)